# Garage Band live transposing MIDI input | Double Midi In signal

Tags: garageband

I use a Native Instruments Komplete Kontrol A49 with Garage Band and Milky. I have set this up with Milky and now have the problem that I have two simultaneous midi in events when playing. Garage Band plays the instrument once originally and once transposed. In addition, I have now downloaded Quick Midi from the App Store and selected "Milky Output" as the midi device. The result is the same. Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: tbh, I don't use any of your components to know quite how they route, but it sounds like you've got two routings running simultaneously; one direct & the other through Milky.